# Store file path in MySQL database and retrieve it using vb2008

Tags: mysql, vb.net, picturebox

I have a form with listbox and picturebox. The lisbox is populated with filename from the database. If the user select one item from listbox the picture should appear on the picturebox. In the MySQL database, I have a table Pix with fields `pixName(varchar)`, `pLocation(varchar)`. In pLocation I saved the file path of the picture.

```
Call Connection()
    With Me
        STRSQL = "Select pLocation From Pix where pixName = " & lstPix.SelectedItem & "'"
        Try
            myCmd.Connection = myConn
            myCmd.CommandText = STRSQL
            reader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
            If reader.Read Then
                Dim path = reader.GetString(0)
                picBox.ImageLocation = path
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("no picture")
        End Try
    End With
```

There's no error when I run it but when I select one in listbox it says "no picture". How can I get this to work? Also, can I use the same code to play video in wmp inside the form?

Comment: Do you store the pathname only in the pLocation field or the full file name?

Comment: I stored the full path of the picture (ex. D:\MyProject\videos\sample.jpg). I browse and found a forum here that \ should not be used because within MySQL string values the backslash is interpreted as an escape character and suggested to alter the path values to contain the "\" sequence to actually store a backslash. So I stored the file path as D:\\MyProject\\videos\\sample.jpg but still failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its clear that your query is missing apostrophe. Change The query to :

```
STRSQL = "Select pLocation From Pix where pixName = '" & lstPix.SelectedItem.ToString() & "'"
```

And a better solution is to use parameters instead :

```
STRSQL = "Select pLocation From Pix where pixName = @pixName"
myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pixName",lstPix.SelectedItem.ToString())
```

Comment: @VBeginner you need to give more details of the error you are getting

Comment: there's no error..the problem is that when I select an item in the list it displays the catch exception message "no picture" even if I already have the full path of the picture stored in the database (example: D:\MyProject\videos\sample.jpg).

Comment: @VBeginner put a break point and see which line is causing the error. the catch `ex` parameter should give you details of the error. try putting this `MsgBox(ex.Message)`

Comment: I got it working now..I still used the same code above and stored the file path with single backslash(\). I think its the apostrophe that I missed. Sorry for bothering you guys, thanks for the effort ^_^v

Comment: when I used the .ToString it didn't work. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
dim kol as string

OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

kol = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.Replace("\", "\\")

TextBox1.Text = kol
```

mysql (insert and update code)